# Iterating an object and accessing its properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I access the properties of james and obtain the below output using console.log statements

> console.log(iterator.next().value);  'James'
>   console.log(iterator.next().value);  5'10
>   console.log(iterator.next().value);  185

```
const james = {  
name: 'James',  
height: `5'10"`,  
weight: 185};  
const key=Object.keys(james);  
const iterator = james[[Symbol.iterator]]();
```

Turn the `james` object into an iterable object.

- Each call to iterator.next should log out an object with the following info:
- key: the key from the `james` object

  - value: the value of the key from the `james` object
  - done: true or false if there are more keys/values

I'm new to JavaScript and programming..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Objects don't natively support an iterator of their values.  One typical way to iterate properties of an object would be something like this:  `Object.keys(james).forEach(prop => {console.log(james[prop])});`.

Comment: You can look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Making your own iterators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

Comment: @jfriend00 why not answer. This is exactly what OP seems to be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following iterator method to the object:

```js
const james = {
  name: 'James',
  height: `5'10"`,
  weight: 185,
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    let nextIndex = 0;
    const entries = Object.entries(this);
      return {
       next: () => {
        if(nextIndex >= entries.length) {
          return {done: true};
        }

        const [key, value] = entries[nextIndex++];

        return {value: { key, value }, done: false};
      }
    };
  }
};

const iterator = james[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);

console.log('----------------');

// or iterate with for...of

for(const vk of james) {
  console.log(vk);
}
```

Or as [@Bergi suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968821/iterating-an-object-and-accessing-its-properties/46969093?noredirect=1#comment80886170_46969093), instead of manually creating the iterator method, you can map the entries to an array of objects, and return the array's iterator:

```js
const james = {
  name: 'James',
  height: `5'10"`,
  weight: 185,
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return Object.entries(this).map(([key, value]) => ({key, value}))[Symbol.iterator]();
  }
};

const iterator = james[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);

console.log('----------------');

// or iterate with for...of

for(const vk of james) {
  console.log(vk);
}
```

Comment: `Object.entries(this).map(([key, value]) => ({key, value}))[Symbol.iterator]()` would've been simpler :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ES8 [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) instead of `Object.keys` in your code to get the values:

```
const iterator = Object.values({  
    name: 'James',  
    height: `5'10"`,  
    weight: 185
})[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(iterator.next().value); // James
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 5'10"
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 185
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already got some good suggestions here, but I figured I'll add one more that can be nice if you can use generators:

```js
const james = {
  name: 'James',
  height: `5'10"`,
  weight: 185,
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this)) {
      yield { key, value };
    }
  },
};
```

of course given

```
const james = {  
  name: 'James',  
  height: `5'10"`,  
  weight: 185,
};  
const key = Object.keys(james);  
const iterator = james[[Symbol.iterator]]();

console.log(iterator.next().value); // 'James'
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 5'10
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 185
```

you could also avoid the custom iterator and do

```
const james = {  
  name: 'James',  
  height: `5'10"`,  
  weight: 185,
};  
const iterator = Object.entries(james)[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator.next()[1]); // 'James'
console.log(iterator.next()[1]); // 5'10
console.log(iterator.next()[1]); // 185
```

or even

```
const james = {  
  name: 'James',  
  height: `5'10"`,  
  weight: 185,
};  
for (const value of Object.values(james)) {
  console.log(value);
}
```